# UISearchbar how to determine if last character typed is a backspace

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a UISearchbar with delegate method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length>3){
 [self updateSearchString:searchText];
}
}
```

updateSearchString goes out to the internet to get the results, formats them and updates the table view. I do not want this to occur if the user hits the backspace key. So I am thinking something like:

```
if(searchText.length>3 && lastCharacterTyped!=backspace){
  }
```

How do i determine the 2nd part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know of a particular way to detect backspace in Objective-C, the most reliable would be to check the length of the string before and after the lastCharacterTyped is typed. if the latter is less, means a backspace was pressed. Hope that helps.

Comment: This did help - got me thinking about it in a different way and solved my problem.